# Create a new GRASS database in R with CRS projection

Tags: raster, r, grass-gis

How to create a new GRASS database in R with CRS projection? I am able to create a new one using the following code but it is not projected

```
require(raster)
require(spgrass6)
initGRASS("/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS", gisDbase="/Users/junf/Documents",
          location='temp',mapset='PERMANENT', override=TRUE)
# gisdbase    /Users/junf/Documents 
# location    temp 
# mapset      PERMANENT 
# rows        1 
# columns     1 
# north       1 
# south       0 
# west        0 
# east        1 
# nsres       1 
# ewres       1 
# projection  NA
```

Now I tried using a projected GeoTiff using the following code which is better but the projection is still NA:

```
r <- as(raster('/Users/junf/Documents/WatershedModel/UpperPulangi/upw_srtm30.tif'), 'SpatialGrid')
initGRASS("/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS", gisDbase="/Users/junf/Documents", location='temp',mapset='PERMANENT', override=TRUE,SG=r)
# gisdbase    /Users/junf/Documents 
# location    temp 
# mapset      PERMANENT 
# rows        3317 
# columns     2774 
# north       950826 
# south       849428.7 
# west        690839.6 
# east        775638 
# nsres       30.56898 
# ewres       30.569 
# projection  NA
```

Can someone please help me create a new GRASS database with WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326) projection
or a projection that matches an existing georeferenced image for import in GRASS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with the following approach which is adopted from [R-sig-Geo](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2016-May/024394.html). First, create a new location via `initGRASS` using the default PERMANENT mapset. Next, set the desired coordinate reference system (CRS). And finally, create a new mapset which will automatically inherit the CRS from PERMANENT.

```
library(rgrass7)

## initialize new location and baseline mapset with required epsg code
gisBase <- system("grass72 --config path", intern = TRUE)

initGRASS(gisBase = gisBase, home = raster::tmpDir(), 
          gisDbase = "~/grassdata", location = "tmp", 
          mapset = "PERMANENT", override = TRUE)

execGRASS("g.proj", flags = "c", epsg = 4326)

## initialize new mapset inheriting projection info
execGRASS("g.mapset", flags = "c", mapset = "new_mapset")
```

Ideally, you should call `g.mapset` and `g.region` with print option enabled afterwards to check if everything is running smoothly.

```
execGRASS("g.mapset", flags = "p")
# new_mapset

execGRASS("g.region", flags = "p")
# projection: 3 (Latitude-Longitude)
# zone:       0
# datum:      wgs84
# ellipsoid:  wgs84
# north:      1N
# south:      0
# west:       0
# east:       1E
# nsres:      1
# ewres:      1
# rows:       1
# cols:       1
# cells:      1
```

Comment: Very nice and simple, this should be the best answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found that it is possible on rgrass7 but not on spgrass6: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Location_Wizard

```
require(rgrass7)
# use epsg code
system('"C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.0.3/grass70" -c epsg:32651 D:/temp/use_epsg')

# use a georeferenced raster
system('"C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.0.3/grass70" -c D:/folder/srtm30.tif D:/temp/use_raster')

# connect to grass database
initGRASS(gisBase='C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.0.3', gisDbase='D:/temp', location='use_raster', mapset='PERMANENT', override = TRUE)
# gisdbase    D:/temp 
# location    rtss 
# mapset      PERMANENT 
# rows        748 
# columns     944 
# north       1253702 
# south       1230844 
# west        732001.4 
# east        760855.3 
# nsres       30.55878 
# ewres       30.56557 
# projection  +proj=utm +no_defs +zone=51 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257223563 +towgs84=0.000,0.000,0.000 +to_meter=1
```

Answer (score 1):

same problem stole several of my precious hours today.

It seems the only workaround is:

```
initGRASS(using whatever location)
```

Then create a new location:

```
execGRASS(
        'g.proj',
        parameters = list(
            georef = [your GeoTiff], 
            location = [new location name]
        )
)

initGRASS(using the new location)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can actually use `rgrass7` instead of `spgrass6` you can achieve what you want with `linkGRASS7` from package **link2GI**. I am using the development version from github here.

```
# devtools::install_github("gisma/link2GI")
library(link2GI)

linkGRASS7(mapview::poppendorf[[5]]) # a raster layer
```

gives

```
gisdbase    /tmp/Rtmpyd2Dh2 
location    file13e5f027f0e 
mapset      PERMANENT 
rows        254 
columns     260 
north       5515185 
south       5507565 
west        654435 
east        662235 
nsres       30 
ewres       30 
projection  +proj=utm +no_defs +zone=32 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257223563 +towgs84=0.000,0.000,0.000 +to_meter=1
```

Note how `linkGRASS7` will by default set up your dbase and location in a temporary location (the temp folder linked to your current R session). You are able to change this by supplying additional arguments `gisdbase` and `location`.

The additional, and probably even higher benefit of **link2GI** is that it will automatically set the correct grass7 environment based on what it finds on your machine (therefore, `linkGRAS7` is somewhat slow - you can skip that part by providing the appropriate settings directly to `linkGRASS7`)