# How to set up a new gdbase and location in rgrass7 in R, through link2GI, different from the temporary one

Tags: r, rgrass7

I am using GRASS on Win 10 through the R environment (RStudio, version 1.0.143) with the link2GI package. 
I would like to assign a new gisdbase and a new location to my project.

I defined my raster(which has a projection and a datum). Then I called up through
link2GI my GRASS version (7.2):

```
library(link2GI)
Lammert_Duens_cropped<-raster(paste0(path_output, "Lammert_cropped.tif"))
link2GI::linkGRASS7(Lammert_Duens_cropped, c("C:\\OSGeo4W64", "grass-7.2.1", "osgeo4W"))
```

It shows, that it has assigned a temporary gisbase and location:

```
GDAL 2.2.0, released 2017/04/28
gisdbase    C:/Users/KELTOS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcbYMjq 
location    file1a6812db316e 
mapset      PERMANENT 
rows        682 
columns     423 
north       5611931 
south       5611249 
west        471482.5 
east        471905.5 
nsres       1 
ewres       1 
projection  +proj=utm +no_defs +zone=32 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257223563 +towgs84=0.000,0.000,0.000 +to_meter=1
```

So far ok. But if I want to say:

```
linkGRASS7(Lammert_Duens_cropped,
       gisdbase = "D:/DAS_PROJEKT/Projektarbeit_R_code/R_chaeology/GRASS",
       location = "Init_project",
       gisdbase_exist = FALSE)
```

R tells me:

> `Error in linkGRASS7(Lammert_Duens_cropped, gisdbase = "D:/DAS_PROJEKT/Projektarbeit_R_code/R_chaeology/GRASS",  :    unused
>   arguments (gisdbase =
>   "D:/DAS_PROJEKT/Projektarbeit_R_code/R_chaeology/GRASS", location =
>   "Init_project", gisdbase_exist = FALSE)`

And if I say:

```
link2GI::linkGRASS7(Lammert_Duens_cropped,
                default_GRASS7 = c("C:\\OSGeo4W64", "grass-7.2.1", "osgeo4W"),
                gisdbase = "D:/DAS_PROJEKT/Projektarbeit_R_code/R_chaeology/GRASS",
                location = "Init_project",
                gisdbase_exist = FALSE)
```

R says the same. R finds Grass, but it doesn't want to assign a new gibsdbase and location, even if I say that gisbas_exist = FALSE.

I know there was an answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232674/98929) that one can change the default dbase and location, but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing, that one must have installed link2GI from github:

```
devtools::install_github("gisma/link2GI", ref = "master", dependencies = TRUE, force = TRUE)
```

and not the "normal" R package!

Additionally, all slashes are / now:

`link2GI::linkGRASS7(Lammert_Duens_cropped,
                    default_GRASS7 = c("C:/OSGeo4W64", "grass-7.2.1", "osgeo4W"),
                    gisdbase = "D:/DAS_PROJEKT/Projektarbeit_R_code/R_chaeology/GRASS",
                    location = "Init_project",
                    gisdbase_exist = FALSE)`

Now it says:

`GDAL 2.2.0, released 2017/04/28
gisdbase    D:/DAS_PROJEKT/Projektarbeit_R_code/R_chaeology/GRASS 
location    Init_project 
mapset      PERMANENT 
rows        682 
columns     423 
north       5611931 
south       5611249 
west        471482.5 
east        471905.5 
nsres       1 
ewres       1 
projection  +proj=utm +no_defs +zone=32 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257223563 +towgs84=0.000,0.000,0.000
+to_meter=1`

Exactly what I wanted :)