# can't initialize projection information in GRASS from R

Tags: r, grass-gis, rgrass7

I want to perform a small calculation in GRASS using the [r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.watershed.html)-function. I convert my raster DEM to a SpatialGridDataFrame to import it into GRASS. However when initializing GRASS the projection information of the DEM-SpatialGridDataFrame is not kept/imported (i.e. `projection(streams_g_buf) # [1] NA`). Can somebody help me to spot the problem?

```
require(raster)
require(rgrass7)

## get Malawi DEM
mwi_dem <- getData("alt", country="MWI", mask=TRUE)

# reproject raster to UTM 36 S
mwidem_trans <- projectRaster(mwi_dem, crs=CRS("+init=epsg:32736"))
# as SpatialGridDataFrame for GRASS
mwidem_trans2 <- as(mwidem_trans, "SpatialGridDataFrame") 

projection(mwidem_trans2) # [1] "+init=epsg:32736 +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

## Initialize GRASS
initGRASS("/usr/lib/grass72", 
          home=tempdir(), override=TRUE, SG=mwidem_trans2)

## Write SpatialGridDataFrame
writeRAST(mwidem_trans2, "DEM", zcol = 1, flags="overwrite")

# GRASS analyses
execGRASS("r.watershed", flags="overwrite",
          parameters=list(elevation="DEM", stream="streams_g", threshold=30))
execGRASS("r.buffer", flags="overwrite",
          parameters=list(input="streams_g", output="streams_g_buf",  distances=200))

## Read back into R
streams_g_buf <- raster(readRAST("streams_g_buf"))

projection(streams_g_buf) # [1] NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your steps up to initGRASS and then ran:

```
execGRASS('g.proj', flags="p")
```

and got:

```
 XY location (unprojected)
```

So the temp location and mapset are created without CRS information. Then when you export back R, you get NA as the CRS.

The answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183032/create-a-new-grass-database-in-r-with-crs-projection) will probably help you. In short you need to create a LOCATION with proper PERMANENT mapset and CRS data, then using that LOCATION, add a mapset, pull in the R raster, then do the GRASS processing and export back to R.